# Why remapping <End> key to <S-A> causes Vim to behave weird?

Tags: vim, vimrc

```
nnoremap <End> <S-A>        " line comment
```

Pressing End key then produces the desired effect but vim also appends `" line comment` to the end of the line!

Is there any way to kinda let vim know where nnoremap directive ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pitfall. After `:map`, everything is taken as the *right-hand side*. I would recommend to place the comment on a separate line:

```
" line comment
nnoremap <End> <S-A>
```

But if you really want to stick with the trailing comments, you can employ the default command separation (with `|`, with in a mapping has to be either escaped `\|` or written as `<Bar>`) to append a separate comment "command":

```
nnoremap <End> <S-A>|        " line comment
```

---

PS: Instead of `<S-A>`, you can simply write `A` [`:help key-notation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation).

Comment: Thanks, @IngoKarkat, using pipe symbol worked! Weird though, escaping the pipe symbol actually breaks the trick for me. Using <Bar> instead of pipe doesn't work either. I use nvim.

Comment: Yes, `<Bar>` or `\|` is for when you want to _include_ the remainder in the mapping, which here is _not_ what you want, so you have to use `|` here. But it's more common the other way around, that's why I mentioned that as well.